# Blank Home Page JHipster Angular4 Gateway

Tags: node.js, angular, jhipster, microservices, gateway

I am facing same kind of issue with Jhipster Gateway application (Angular 4) in some machines only,

I am doing below common steps to check out application from SVN and run the application

1. We are loading the source code for below files of the application from SVN (Please look in to the image)

[image: Files Structure]

2. After that ran 'npm install/yarn install'
3. After that I have ran **mvnw** and **yarn start** in parallel CMD windows

Application is working fine with 9000 port (Provided by yarn), but I am unable to see home page with port 8080. It is not showing any exceptions or errors also.

But in some systems it fine working fine, I am confused how to solve this.

**Here is the log**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Agree Gateway V 1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ agree-gateway-v-1 >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (default-resources) @ agree-gateway-v-1 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 11 resources
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ agree-gateway-v-1 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 11 resources
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ agree-gateway-v-1 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ agree-gateway-v-1 ---
[INFO] argLine set to "-javaagent:C:\\Users\\NSPL-1508\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.9\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=E:\\Recon Workspace New\\AgreeGateway\\target\\test-results\\coverage\\jacoco\\jacoco.exec" -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) @ agree-gateway-v-1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ agree-gateway-v-1 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ agree-gateway-v-1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ agree-gateway-v-1 <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ agree-gateway-v-1 ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Ignoring Class-Path entry lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar found inC:\Users\NSPL-1508\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar as C:\Users\NSPL-1508\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\lib\snakeyaml-1.13.jar does not exist
17:17:04.940 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
17:17:04.945 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
17:17:04.946 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/E:/Recon%20Workspace%20New/AgreeGateway/target/classes/]
2017-08-28 17:17:07.200 DEBUG 5004 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE ::
:: https://jhipster.github.io ::

2017-08-28 17:17:08.569  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.AgreeGatewayV1App           : The following profiles are active: swagger,dev
2017-08-28 17:17:11.643 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.AsyncConfiguration   : Creating Async Task Executor
2017-08-28 17:17:12.800 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.nspl.app.config.MetricsConfiguration   : Registering JVM gauges
2017-08-28 17:17:12.860 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.nspl.app.config.MetricsConfiguration   : Monitoring the datasource
2017-08-28 17:17:12.868 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.nspl.app.config.MetricsConfiguration   : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2017-08-28 17:17:14.198 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.CacheConfiguration   : Configuring Hazelcast
2017-08-28 17:17:14.229 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.CacheConfiguration   : Configuring Hazelcast clustering for instanceId: agreeGatewayV1
2017-08-28 17:17:14.229 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.CacheConfiguration   : Application is running with the "dev" profile, Hazelcast cluster will only work with localhost instances
2017-08-28 17:17:14.365  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2017-08-28 17:17:14.695  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-08-28 17:17:14.696  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-08-28 17:17:14.854  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2017-08-28 17:17:14.863  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2017-08-28 17:17:15.166  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2017-08-28 17:17:15.262  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2017-08-28 17:17:15.263  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2017-08-28 17:17:15.269  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2017-08-28 17:17:15.269  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2017-08-28 17:17:15.270  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2017-08-28 17:17:15.271  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2017-08-28 17:17:15.279  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2017-08-28 17:17:15.429  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2017-08-28 17:17:15.434  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 5
2017-08-28 17:17:15.443  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 12
2017-08-28 17:17:15.462  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1503920835462 with initial instances count: 1
2017-08-28 17:17:15.614 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.CacheConfiguration   : Adding Hazelcast (dev) cluster member 127.0.0.1:13781
2017-08-28 17:17:15.671  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker        : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7.7] Picked [127.0.0.1]:13781, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=13781], bind any local is true
2017-08-28 17:17:15.695  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] Hazelcast 3.7.7 (20170404 - e3c56ea) starting at [127.0.0.1]:13781
2017-08-28 17:17:15.697  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2017-08-28 17:17:15.702  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
2017-08-28 17:17:15.934  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] Backpressure is disabled
2017-08-28 17:17:16.354 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] Updating members [Member [127.0.0.1]:13781 - 11614668-abd2-48d1-bc55-84e4ce6e6534 this]
2017-08-28 17:17:16.362 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.i.p.InternalPartitionService         : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] Adding Member [127.0.0.1]:13781 - 11614668-abd2-48d1-bc55-84e4ce6e6534 this
2017-08-28 17:17:16.383  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] Creating TcpIpJoiner
2017-08-28 17:17:16.526  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] Starting 4 partition threads
2017-08-28 17:17:16.528  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] Starting 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2017-08-28 17:17:16.536  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] [127.0.0.1]:13781 is STARTING
2017-08-28 17:17:16.537 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.i.p.InternalPartitionService         : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] Adding Member [127.0.0.1]:13781 - 11614668-abd2-48d1-bc55-84e4ce6e6534 this
2017-08-28 17:17:16.539  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 3 input threads and 3 output threads
2017-08-28 17:17:16.540 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] IO threads selector mode is SELECT
2017-08-28 17:17:16.567 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner   : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] [127.0.0.1]:13781 is local? true
2017-08-28 17:17:16.569 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner   : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] This node will assume master role since no possible member where connected to.
2017-08-28 17:17:16.570 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner   : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] PostJoin master: [127.0.0.1]:13781, isMaster: true
2017-08-28 17:17:16.571  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner   : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7]


Members [1] {
        Member [127.0.0.1]:13781 - 11614668-abd2-48d1-bc55-84e4ce6e6534 this
}

2017-08-28 17:17:16.867  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.7.7] [127.0.0.1]:13781 is STARTED
2017-08-28 17:17:17.932 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.WebConfigurer        : Registering CORS filter
2017-08-28 17:17:18.142  WARN 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2017-08-28 17:17:18.602  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.WebConfigurer        : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
2017-08-28 17:17:18.609 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.WebConfigurer        : Initializing Metrics registries
2017-08-28 17:17:18.615 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.WebConfigurer        : Registering Metrics Filter
2017-08-28 17:17:18.621 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.WebConfigurer        : Registering Metrics Servlet
2017-08-28 17:17:18.625  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.WebConfigurer        : Web application fully configured
2017-08-28 17:17:18.955 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.nspl.app.config.DatabaseConfiguration  : Configuring Liquibase
2017-08-28 17:17:18.968  WARN 5004 --- [-v-1-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2017-08-28 17:17:20.560  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.h.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory        : Starting up HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
2017-08-28 17:17:20.661  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.h.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory  : Using existing HazelcastInstance [agreeGatewayV1].
2017-08-28 17:17:20.791  INFO 5004 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_AGREEGATEWAYV1/agreeGatewayV1:bd66d684631aa5c9bfbec0fc594b7207 - Re-registering apps/AGREEGATEWAYV1
2017-08-28 17:17:20.792  INFO 5004 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_AGREEGATEWAYV1/agreeGatewayV1:bd66d684631aa5c9bfbec0fc594b7207: registering service...
2017-08-28 17:17:20.814 DEBUG 5004 --- [-v-1-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 1843 ms
2017-08-28 17:17:20.859  INFO 5004 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_AGREEGATEWAYV1/agreeGatewayV1:bd66d684631aa5c9bfbec0fc594b7207 - registration status: 204
2017-08-28 17:17:24.980 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.config.CacheConfiguration   : Starting HazelcastCacheManager
2017-08-28 17:17:28.070 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Starting Swagger
2017-08-28 17:17:28.081 DEBUG 5004 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Started Swagger in 6 ms
2017-08-28 17:17:29.329  WARN 5004 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2017-08-28 17:17:29.565  WARN 5004 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with key 'zuulEndpoint' has been registered as an MBean but has no exposed attributes or operations
2017-08-28 17:17:30.066  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1503920850066, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2017-08-28 17:17:30.833  INFO 5004 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_AGREEGATEWAYV1/agreeGatewayV1:bd66d684631aa5c9bfbec0fc594b7207: registering service...
2017-08-28 17:17:31.038  INFO 5004 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_AGREEGATEWAYV1/agreeGatewayV1:bd66d684631aa5c9bfbec0fc594b7207 - registration status: 204
2017-08-28 17:17:31.329  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.AgreeGatewayV1App           : Started AgreeGatewayV1App in 26.345 seconds (JVM running for 27.598)
2017-08-28 17:17:31.338  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.AgreeGatewayV1App           :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'agreeGatewayV1' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:8080
        External:       http://192.168.0.33:8080
        Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
2017-08-28 17:17:31.346  INFO 5004 --- [  restartedMain] com.nspl.app.AgreeGatewayV1App           :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Config Server:  Connected to the JHipster Registry config server!
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: When you are in dev profile you access the UI on port 9000 not on port 8080, the port 8080 is used only for API calls. This is the only way to get hot reload for the UI.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in dev, you access the UI on port 9000 (webpack) not on port 8080 (spring boot), the port 8080 is used only for API calls. This is the only way to get hot reload for the UI.

If you really want to access the UI in dev on port 8080, each time you make a change you have to run `yarn webpack:build` and then restart the spring boot app.

Comment: Yes, you are right Marziou. I did the same thing ran **yarn webpack:build** then **mvnw** but no change in result.